# python fragmented data pandas , DASK

Tags: python, django, pandas, dask

what is the difference of using

```
//DASK
b = db.from_sequence(_query,npartitions=2)
df = b.to_dataframe()
df = df.compute()  

//PANDAS
df = pd.DataFrame(_query)
```

I want to choose the best option to fragment large amounts of data and without losing performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Dask's best practices with dataframes https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-best-practices.html, for data that fits into RAM, use Pandas, it will probably be more efficient.

If you choose to use Dask, avoid very large partitions. If manually changing partition count, take into account your available memory and cores. For instance a machine with 100 GB and 10 cores would typically want partitions in the 1 GB range.

As of Dask 2.0.0 you can do that by using something like: 
df.repartition(partition_size="100MB")

Other tips I can offer if you choose to stick with Dask is setting up a local client where you can take advantage of Dask Distributed http://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/client.html. From there avoid full data shuffling and reduce as far as you can before computing to Pandas.

Comment: I am a little confused about partitions and memory usage, this is not there or in cache or is it? And what can slow the server?